# Endless loading of my NodeJS API site, if username doesnt exist on my LDAP Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, ldapjs

im trying to program a RestfulAPI with NodeJS, ExpressJS and LdapJS. I want to do a user profile page where the user is able to see his attributes on the LDAP Server and can change them.

If i enter a valid uid in the Request-URL the server find the user successfully and respond the wanted attributes of that user which can be seen via browser and postman for example.
My problem now is, that if the given "uid" respectively the user itself doesn't exist on my LDAP-Server the site keeps loading endlessly and don't put out any error or any kind of response...

Here is my current code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const ldap = require('ldapjs');
const client = ldap.createClient({
    url: 'ldap://ldap.example.de:389',
    timeout: 30000,
    reconnect: true
});

client.bind('cn=readonly,dc=example,dc=de', 'secret', function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
});

router.get('/:username', function(req, res) {
    let opts = {
        scope: 'sub',
        filter: `(uid=${req.params.username})`,
        // attributes: ['givenName', 'sn', 'jpegPhoto', 'mail', 'uid']
        attributes: ['givenName', 'sn', 'mail', 'uid'] //example attributes (not final)
    }

    client.search('ou=User,dc=example,dc=de', opts, function(err, result) {
        if(err) throw err;

        result.on('searchEntry', function(entry){
            res.send(entry.object);
        });

        result.on('searchReference', function(referral) {
            console.log('referral: ' + referral);
        });

        res.on('error', function(err) {
            console.error('error: ' + err.message);
        });

        res.on('end', function(result) {
            console.log('status: ' + result.status);
        });
    });
});
```

I searched everywhere for a solution or a likely problem but couldn't find anything. So i have to ask you guys ^^
I hope you can help me out

**Updated Code with help by Klaycon:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const ldap = require('ldapjs');
const client = ldap.createClient({
    url: 'ldap://ldap.example.de:389',
    timeout: 30000,
    reconnect: true
});

client.bind('cn=readonly,dc=example,dc=de', 'secret', function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
});

router.get('/:username', function(req, res) {
    let opts = {
        scope: 'sub',
        filter: `(uid=${req.params.username})`,
        // attributes: ['givenName', 'sn', 'jpegPhoto', 'mail', 'uid']
        attributes: ['givenName', 'sn', 'mail', 'uid'] //example attributes (not final)
    }

    client.search('ou=User,dc=example,dc=de', opts, function(err, result) {
        if(err) throw err;

        result.on('searchEntry', function(entry){
            res.send(entry.object);
        });

        result.on('searchReference', function(referral) {
            console.log('referral: ' + referral);
        });

        result.on('error', function(err) {
            console.error('error: ' + err.message);
        });

        result.on('end', function(resu) {
            console.log('status: ' + resu.status);
            if(resu.status != 0) res.status(404).send("User not found");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: For starters, get rid of every instance of `if(err) throw err;` and replace it with something that logs the error and implements some real error handling.  You are just eating errors with no logging so if something goes wrong, your request will just hang and never complete.  You should never, ever write `if(err) throw err;` inside a plain asynchronous callback.  It does nothing useful (you can't catch that exception anywhere) and provides no logging.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [ldapjs docs](http://ldapjs.org/client.html#search):

> Responses from the search method are an EventEmitter where you will
>   get a notification for each searchEntry that comes back from the
>   server. You will additionally be able to listen for a searchReference,
>   error and end event. Note that the error event will only be for
>   client/TCP errors, not LDAP error codes like the other APIs. You'll
>   want to check the LDAP status code (likely for 0) on the end event to
>   assert success.

If the search does not return results, `result` will never emit `searchEntry` but will emit `end` instead. Right now you only *ever* call `res.send()` in the event that the `searchEntry` event is fired - but what if it never is? You'll need to listen to the `end` event and handle the case that no result was found, returning a response to the user accordingly. It looks like you tried to do this as your example is very similar to that from the docs, but you at least forgot to change `res` to `result`.

```
result.on('end', function(result) {
    console.log('status: ' + result.status);
    if(result.status != 0) res.status(404).send({ message: "User not found" }); //customize as needed
});
```

Comment: wow xD ok i saw my typing mistake now. i changed everything now to the right values. i changed both "res.on" to "result.on" and added your 404 status showing into the "end-function".
I finally see the statuscode in the console, when the search is calling the end-function. But the site keeps loading if i search for an non existing uid somehow. Means it doesnt show the 404 not found message and the statuscode is still 0...
Any more ideas?

Put an updated version of my code in the main post.